# Performing multiple regex match on pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have an extraction of email body strings loaded in a dataframe under `df['Body']`
All I need is to perform matches with regex codes, when one of the regex matches, it should assign a category based on what regex received a match.

For that I am trying to:

1. make a for loop going through `df['Body']`
2. check the iterated string and execute regex matches
3. based on matched regex, print into label column "regex1 matched" or "regex2 matched" etc.

I started with a simple for loop below but cant get it to work even with only one regex check and console print.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Body_List.xlsx', header=None, index=False, names=['Body','Label'])

regex = re.compile(r"(?s)^(?=.*\b(?:[Uu]nblock|[Ss]onderfreigabe|[Rr]elease|[Ff]reigeben|[Ff]reigabe|[Ff]reischalten|[Oo][Rr][Dd])\b).*\b([47]\d{6}|\d{7})\b")


for message in (df['Body']):
    if re.match(regex, message)== True:                   
  
        print("regex matched " + df['Label'])
    else:

        print("regex didnt matched" + df['Label'])
```

What I receive after execution:

[image]

Could anyone please help how to make this loop work + have this implemented for multiple regex checks?

Thank you very much!

Examples of other regex checks:

```
release_test = re.compile('\b((4|7)\d{6})\b')
account_test = re.compile('\b((1)\d{6})\b|(\account|Account|Konto|konto|Tili|tili|účet|ucet|Compte|compte)')
```

Comment: Are you trying to see if there is a match? `df['Body'].str.contains(r'(?s)^(?=.*\b(?:[Uu]nblock|[Ss]onderfreigabe|[Rr]elease|[Ff]reigeben|[Ff]reigabe|[Ff]reischalten|[Oo][Rr][Dd])\b).*\b[47]\d{6}\b')`?

Comment: Yes, these options I worked with but it wont allow me to populate df['Label'] based on matched condition. Let alone checking 3 regex codes per df['Body'] item and populating df['Label'] based on that.

Comment: Do, do you mean you want to extract the numbers? `df['Body'].str.extract(r'(?s)^(?=.*\b(?:[Uu]nblock|[Ss]onderfreigabe|[Rr]elease|[Ff]reigeben|[Ff]reigabe|[Ff]reischalten|[Oo][Rr][Dd])\b).*\b([47]\d{6})\b', expand=False)`?

Comment: My dataframe has two columns. df['Body'] and empty df['Label'].
I have 3 regex functions that i want to perform on each row of df['Body']
If, for example, regex 1 matches, it should print into df['Label'] something like "regex 1 matched". Hope it makes sense. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Run the code similar in the top comment and create 3 columns for the 3 regexps. Then you can use them to populate your `Label` column.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew! Was a good tip creating separate columns and label data based on their results - works now as expected. Though, I am surprised that ordinary for loops / if conditions were such a problem in case of regex.

Comment: You are welcome to post your solution.

Answer (score 2):

After using code snippet from @WiktorStribiżew as an inspiration, I was able to create 2 columns with regex checks inside of my pandas dataframe with use of `np.where`. This will now enable me to categorize `df['Body']` contents based on each regex match.

Thank you!

Code solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import re


df = pd.read_excel('Regex testing 2.xlsx', header=None, index=False, names=['Sender','Subject', 'Body','Date','Time','Category', 'Folder','Regex1','Regex2'])


regex1 = re.compile(r"(?si)^(?=.*\b(?:unblock|kredit|sonderfreigabe|unlock|release|freigeben|freigabe|freischalten|ord)\b).*\b([47]\d{6}|\d{8})\b")

regex2 = re.compile(r"\b((1)\d{6})\b|(\account|Account|Konto|konto|Tili|tili|účet|ucet|Compte|compte)")


df['Regex1'] = np.where(df.Body.str.match(regex1), "Body matched regex1", "Body not matching regex1")

df['Regex2'] = np.where(df.Body.str.match(regex2), "Body matched regex1", "Body not matching regex1")


# export to excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'RegexOutput.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'strings_to_urls': False})
df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.close()
```